# Can't clone git repo from GitLab on Windows 10

Tags: gitlab, window

Windows 10 (64 bit)

I can success clone git repo from GitHub on Windows 10.

Nice.

But from GitLab I can't clone git repo.

I get error:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/some-project/android

Cloning into 'android'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/some-project/android.git/'
```

But if I try same command (`git clone https://gitlab.com/some-project/android)`  on Linux Machine I success clone git repo from GitLab.

Why I can't download git repo on windows 10 machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `Control Panel` -> search for `Credential Manager` -> `Windows Credentials` -> search for `git:https://gitlab.com` and `Edit` it with your GitLab user you logged in your linux machine, then try again.